# Where Is Signature Data Stored In Post-SegWit Transactions?

Tags: transactions, block, script, segregated-witness, signature

If i'm correct, i am pretty sure that signature data such as the `scriptsigsize`
and `scriptsig` is stored outside the Tx_Data of a Bitcoin transaction. But then where is it stored? Is it in the block or is it somehow connected to the transaction-data?

Also, how is it possible that this Bitcoin included in the transaction can be unlocked if the signature data is external from the transaction?

Answer (score 4):

From the perspective of new post-segwit nodes, the witness data **is** part of the transaction data. It is serialized in a new field, after all the transaction outputs, before the locktime field.

However, this field is stripped out before relaying to old pre-segwit nodes. So from the perspective of those old nodes, the witness data isn't just external - it just doesn't exist. They don't care about the witness data, as to them, these outputs are the equivalent of "True": anyone can spend them without any signatures.